# Passing image into bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I have a list of images. User can click on any image and it will open a bootstrap modal. In this boostrap modal, I need the image, that the user clicked on, to appear.

Please, view my comments in the below code for more clarity.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<center>
  <div id="items" class="transitions-enabled">
    <% @images.each do |image| %>
      <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <div class="square_item_image">
          #HERE IS THE IMAGE I WANT TO APPEAR IN THE BOOSTRAP MODAL
          <%= image_tag(image["images"]["low_resolution"]["url"]) %>
        </div>
        <div class="item_info">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create Outfit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</center>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        #I WOULD LIKE THE IMAGE TO APPEAR HERE
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by using javascript you can do it

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddImgDialog", function () {
 var imgsrc = $(this).data('id');
 $('#my_image').attr('src',imgsrc););
});
```

HTML code

```
<div class="item_info">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg open-AddImgDialog" data-id="img/img.jpg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create Outfit</button>
</div>
```

MODAL Pop

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <img id="my_image" />
 </div>
```

Here data-id="img/img.jpg" is your image path and add class name open-AddImgDialog in button.

Answer (score 0):

Is there one too many ";" in
$('#my_image').attr('src',imgsrc););

Should be:
$('#my_image').attr('src',imgsrc));